# Equation of motion through the Lagrangian with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, dynamic, nonlinear, constraint

I ask for advice, I'm a little confused. I have such a Lagrangian.

$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)-\lambda(2x^2+3y^2-1^2)$

Here $\lambda(2x^2+3y^2-1^2)$ is the constraint on the phase variables.

I need to derive the equation of motion given the constraints and solve them *numerically* with the help of `NDSolve`.

We do this in accordance with the classic formula:

$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dL}{d\dot{q}})-\frac{dL}{dq}=0$

Where $q=[x,y]$ are generalized coordinates.  *I'm not sure about the Lagrange multiplier as a generalized coordinate.*

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

T = 1/2 m (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2);(*Kinetic Energy*)

f = \[Lambda] (2 x[t]^2 + 3 y[t]^2 - 1^2);(*Constraint*)

L = T - f;(*Lagrangian*)

D[D[L, x'[t]], t] - D[L, x[t]];

D[D[L, y'[t]], t] - D[L, y[t]];

D[D[L, \[Lambda]'[t]], t] - D[L, \[Lambda][t]];
```

**Question:** how are the Lagrange multipliers included in this system when compiling the ODE system and numerically solving it?

**EDIT (with correct initial conditions and another constraint):**

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

q = Function[t, {x[t], y[t]}];(*coordinates*)

zwang = x[t] + x[t] y[t] + y[t] - 1;(*constraints*)

Solve[zwang == 0, y[t]];

Q = \[Lambda][t] D[zwang, {q[t]}];(*gen.forces*)

L = 1/2 (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2);

eqn = D[D[L, {q'[t]}], t] - 
   D[L, {q[t]}] - \[Lambda][t] D[zwang, {q[t]}];


sol = Solve[
    Join[eqn, {D[zwang, {t, 2}]}] == 0, {x''[t], 
     y''[t], \[Lambda][t]}][[1]];

x0 = 1/2;

y0 = 1/3;

s = NDSolve[{sol[[1, 1]] == sol[[1, 2]], sol[[2, 1]] == sol[[2, 2]], 
    sol[[3, 1]] == sol[[3, 2]], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, x'[0] == 0, 
    y'[0] == 0}, {x, y, \[Lambda]}, {t, 500}];

Plot[Evaluate[zwang /. s], {t, 0, 500}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: \[Lambda] is a constant, the derivative would be zero. Instead you need to use the equation of the constrain: x^2+y^2-1==0

Comment: @DanielHuber Yes, I agree. As for the second remark, constraint equation does not contain derivatives. This means that the system of ODE will include algebraic constraints, with such systems, as far as I know, acceptable in Mathematica. Is that correct?

Comment: Which of the constraints is the correct one: `2 x[t]^2 + 3 y[t]^2 ==1^2` or `x[t]^2 +   y[t]^2 ==1^2`  ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann First. I have fixed the error in the question :)

Comment: Have a look at: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/lectures/node90.html

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks for this very interesting link!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Can you rewrite your answer based on this book?

Comment: @DanielHuber Perhaps you also  know a link which describes a generalized form of *principle of d'Alembert with constraints* ? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Please see also https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0045782588900850

Comment: Hi Ulrich, out of my mind I do not know a googd link. But you could search by: "LAGRANGE–D’ALEMBERT". One often deals with choosing generalized coordinates that fulfill the constrains and then constrains need not be considered.

Comment: @DanialHuber Thanks for your answer, perhaps I'll find a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember Lagrangeformalism (classic form)  is only valid for generalized coordinates, which fullfill the constraints . In your example `x[t],y[t]` aren't generalized coordinates!

For the constraint  `2 x[t]^2 + 3 y[t]^2 ==1^2` possible generalized coordinate `q[t]` would be `x[t]->Cos[q[t]]/Sqrt[2],y[t]->Sin[q[t]]/Sqrt[3]`

```
2 x[t]^2 + 3 y[t]^2 ==1^2 /.{x[t]->Cos[q[t]]/Sqrt[2],y[t]->Sin[q[t]]/Sqrt[3]}// Simplify
(*True*)

L= 1/2 m (3 x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2) /. {x -> ( Cos[q[#]]/Sqrt[2] &), y  -> (Sin[q[#]]/Sqrt[3] &)} //Simplify
(*-(1/24) m (-11 + 7 Cos[2 q[t]]) Derivative[1][q][t]^2*)
```

The equations of motion follow to

```
D[D[L, q'[t]], t] - D[L, q[t]]==0
(*7/12 m Sin[2 q[t]] Derivative[1][q][t]^2 -1/12 m (-11 + 7 Cos[2 q[t]]) (q^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]*)
```

Hope it helps!

**addendum Lagrange with constraints** (thanks @DanielHuber's comment )

```
q = Function[t, {x[t], \[CurlyPhi][t]}]; (*coordinates*)
zwang = x[t] - r \[CurlyPhi][t] (* constraints *)
Q = \[Lambda][t] D[zwang, {q[t]}] (* gen. forces*)

L = 1/2 m x'[t]^2 + 1/2 \[Theta] \[CurlyPhi]'[t]^2 +m g Sin[\[Alpha]]  x[t]
eqn = D[D[L, {q'[t]}], t] -D[L, {q[t]}] - \[Lambda][t] D[zwang, {q[t]}]
```

From equations `eqn` and `zwang` the Lagrange multiplier  `\[Lambda][t]`is evaluated, substitution gives the equations of motion

```
sol = Solve[Join[eqn, {D[zwang, {t, 2}]}] ==0, {x''[t], \[CurlyPhi]''[t], \[Lambda][t]}][[1]]
(*{(x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] -> (g m r^2 Sin[\[Alpha]])/(m r^2 + \[Theta]), (\[CurlyPhi]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] -> (g m r Sin[\[Alpha]])/(m r^2 + \[Theta]), \[Lambda][t] -> -((g m \[Theta] Sin[\[Alpha]])/(m r^2 + \[Theta]))}*)

Q /. sol (* Reibkraft und -moment*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is relevant in this rather narrow case. I would like to get a solution for a wider class of equations. Let's say for the Lagrangian $L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)$ and constraint $f=\lambda(x+3xy+y^2-1)$. What will be the system of equation ODE.

Comment: I answered the question you asked for. In this new example substitute `x[t]-> (1 - y[t]^2)/(1 + 3 y[t]))` ,  Lagrangian follows to  `L=(m (5 + 12 y[t] + 38 y[t]^2 + 60 y[t]^3 + 45 y[t]^4) Derivative[1][y][
  t]^2)/(1 + 3 y[t])^4`  with generalized coordinate `y[t]`

Comment: I beg your pardon for inattention. I am reading this in the middle of the night and I guess it's time for me to take a nap :) how did you get such a substitution? Expressed it from the constraint?

Comment: I tried to solve the constraints  `Solve[x + 3 x y + y^2 \[Minus] 1 == 0, x]`.

Comment: My modified answer shows how to proceed! You could check your results on your own I think.

Comment: I tried the method you suggested. Numerical equations are solved, the dynamics of the Lagrangian multiplier is present. But! The specified restriction `zwang` is not met. Please, see my EDIT in topic.

Comment: In your edit the initial conditions doesn't fullfill the constraint: `zwang /. t -> 0 /. {x[0] -> 1/2, y[0] -> 1/4} (*-1/8 !=0 *)`

Comment: Yes, I have already fixed this error. And the principle is now more or less completely clear to me, it seems.

Comment: Fine! But still in your edit you are using wrong initial conditions...

Comment: I added code with correct initial conditions. Perhaps someone will find it useful in his work.